# Backbone select option in initialize

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I have some forms in API that those name are called in select options. I want to get the form one for the first time that the page is initialised.

HTML of select options is:

```
<fieldset>
   <label class="float-left" for="dropdown1">{{locale "forms"}}</label>
   <select id="dropdown1" class="form-control">
     {{#each options}}
      <option value="{{id}}">{{formType}} - {{name}}</option> <br>
      {{/each}}
   </select>
</fieldset>
```

Also I have the model with the name ModelForm and I have instantiate the model in this way (because I need in this way)

```
initialize() {
  this.collection = new ModelForm();
  this.model = new ModelForm();
  this.synced = false;
  this.id = undefined;
}
```

I have make a function that call model and collection on change and it works.

```
getSelectedOption(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
const modelFormId = +ev.target.value;
if (modelFormId) {
  this.id = modelFormId;
  this.model.set({ ...this.collection.get(modelFormId).toJSON() });
  this.$('.page-actions').css('display', 'block');
 }
}
```

So again what I want is, how to initialise that for the first time to get selected option one (form name one) and to fill all other fields with data that comes for this form name?

Comment: `this.collection = new ModelForm();
  this.model = new ModelForm();` mapping a model to collection property seem like a very bad practice...

Comment: What is `options`? Where is the values stored? Is this view rendering a collection? How is the rendering/event binding done? Can't you just do `this.collection.get(0)` and render the form with its details?

Comment: @TJ values are stored in the API. I'm getting the values from the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the `initialize` method of the `View` that extended from the Backbone.View` object

you will need to add event listener like:

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'sync', this.renderOptions);
```

You can see full example at my [project](https://github.com/ShaharShokrani/CalendarEvents/blob/master/static/js/views/filtersView.js).